# using dynamicFields with datastax enterprise search

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I'm using Datastax Enterprise 4.8.0 with Search enabled. I'm trying to use dynamicFields with a map collection and can't figure it out. Here's more details.

`[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.9.791 | DSE 4.8.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]`

I've got a cluster of 3 nodes with Search enabled. I'm using a map field `properties map<text, text>` and now I want to search on that from datastax solr using a dynamicField definition.

In schema.xml, I've got the following, which isn't working:

`<dynamicField name="properties*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />`

In system.log, I'm seeing errors like this:

`WARN  [http-0.0.0.0-8983-6] 2016-03-01 18:07:02,075  Cql3CassandraRowReader.java:162 - Cannot find dynamic field : [description], please make sure [properties] is being prepended/appended accordingly to build a correct dynamic field name. Did you mean propertiesdescription? descriptionproperties?`

I haven't figured out how to alter the field definition to resolve the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you insert your map value?

Using CQL, insert data into the map using the base name as a prefix or suffix in the first component of each map pair.

See details here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchDynFlds.html

Comment: can't believe I overlooked that. thanks! that put me on the right trail